# Inserting a row cloned from one table into a specific location of another table

Tags: javascript, html, insert, row

I have two HTML tables; a source address table and a destination address table where I want to shift rows from the source table to the destination table, and vice-versa.
It is *mostly* working, but I am getting stuck when **inserting** a row into the destination table from the source table. I do not want to **append** a row, as the last row in the destination table supports a text field where the user can type in an address manually. Below is the handler function for when a user clicks on a row in the source address table to remove and shift that row into the destination table:

```
$("#source_christmas_lights_addresses .move-row").live("click", function() {

var tr = $(this).closest("#source_christmas_lights_addresses tbody tr").remove().clone();

//The below line of code has been removed because I don't want to add my row to the end of the table.
//$("#destination_christmas_lights_addresses tbody").append(tr);


//Below here is new code added to insert a row
var tableRef = document.getElementById('destination_christmas_lights_addresses').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

//Insert a row into the destination table before the end of route address.
var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length -1);

//Insert a cell in the row at index 0
var newCell  = newRow.insertCell(0);
newCell.innerHTML = "I want inner HTML from variable tr here";

});
```

**PROBLEM 1**
When I use the **append** function (commented out) it all works fine, except the row is at the bottom of the table which I do not want. 
When I use the **insertRow** function, I can not work out how to move the appropriate elements of the tr variable to create a new row. I need the innerHTML because it includes code to enable the shifting of the row back into the source table.
Somebody please help?

**PROBLEM 2** I am sure that the following line of code can written differently.

```
var tableRef = document.getElementById('destination_christmas_lights_addresses').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
```

I thought I could use:

```
var tableRef = $("#destination_christmas_lights_addresses tbody");
```

but I can't get this to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks for peoples responses. Final solution which solves both my problems is as follows.

```
$("#source_christmas_lights_addresses .move-row").live("click", function() {

var tr = $(this).closest("#source_christmas_lights_addresses tbody tr").remove().clone();

//reference id of element representing the row I want to add the address before.
$("#trip_planner_end_address_row").before(tr);

      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var $WhereToAppend=('#destination_christmas_lights_addresses').find('tr:first');

($tr).insertBefore($WhereToAppend);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. From your answer I realised there were a few other functions (such as InsertBefore) I hadn't tried. As I was using jquery all I needed to do was to add the following line and reference the id of the element I wanted to put my address before. Solutions is as follows:

 $("#trip_planner_end_address_row").before(tr);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is "remove method and the clone", you should save the cloned tr in a variable for then remove the original tr. 
Like this:

```
var tr_original = $(this).closest("#source_christmas_lights_addresses tbody tr");
var tr_cloned = tr_original.clone();
tr_original.remove();
```

I would like see your original sample code, so it would be easy to understand the real trouble ;)
Good luck !